# The number of instances of a cell editor?

Tags: java, instance, render

Reading an old Java Swing book by O'Reilly and it shows the piece of code listed below.

The book also reads :
***Notice that each call to getListCellRendererComponent() returns the same instance. This is very important for performance. Creating a new instance each time the method is called would place needless strain on the system.***

My understanding (which may be wrong) is that each cell will have its own implementation of this Cell Renderer unless maybe the BookCellRenderer class was defined as **static**.

Does each cell have its own instance of a Cell Renderer?
Should the class be static to ensure there is only one instance?
What is it about this specific class that only produces one instance?

```
// BookCellRenderer.java
// A custom cell renderer for BookEntry objects.
//
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class BookCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {
private static final Color HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = new Color(0, 0, 128);

public BookCellRenderer() {
    setOpaque(true);
    setIconTextGap(12);
}

public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
    JList list,
    Object value,
    int index,
    boolean isSelected,
    boolean cellHasFocus)
{
    BookEntry entry = (BookEntry)value;
    setText(entry.getTitle());
    setIcon(entry.getImage());
    if(isSelected) {
        setBackground(HIGHLIGHT_COLOR);
        setForeground(Color.white);
    } else {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setForeground(Color.black);
    }
    return this;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, each cell does not have its own instance (you can validate this simply by breakpointing your constructor). There's nothing magic going on here; you are the one who instantiates the renderer, so how could there be X * Y instances?

If you're confused about why this is safe: the returned component is used to render the cell, but then is free to be used by the next call to `getListCellRendererComponent`.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html#getListCellRendererComponent-javax.swing.JList-E-int-boolean-boolean-):

> Return a component that has been configured to display the specified value. That component's paint method is then called to "render" the cell.

In other words, the component is only used to do the `paint`, and then not used further.  This is why it's safe to use a singleton component (i.e. return the same component every time).

There is no need to define a singleton/static renderer.